How to increase Zoom level in flutter_cached_pdf view package without interactive viewer
Basically i am using flutter_cached_pdfview package and in that the amount of zoom level is so less i want more zooming on the pdfs because the pdf's contain newspaper so how to do that \
I tried interactive viewer on top of the this widget but the quality of the pdf decreased on the pinch zoom and also issues of sliding the pdf from left to right

I'm not exactly sure, I looked at the package. The package you are using is a different development of an existing package, but it ultimately uses the flutter_pdfview package.

I also examined this package "flutter_pdfview" and I don't know if it is related to the exact function you mentioned, but the pdf operations of the package are natively coded and some parameters are statically assigned.

For example '_pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 4.0;' If you want to change this part, first download the 'flutter_pdfview' package and make your own changes, then download the 'flutter_cached-pdfview' package and add the package you edited instead of the 'flutter_pdfview' it refers to. Finally, you can add the package you created to your own project.

there is no property like pdfView.maxScaleFactor

in IOS https://github.com/endigo/flutter_pdfview/blob/master/ios/Classes/FlutterPDFView.m#L143
